# Can't install Steam on fresh Debian Buster install

Tags: debian, x86, steam

I just installed a fresh Debian install and I can't install Steam and PCSX2, both depending on i386 packages.

I followed the classic procedure:

```
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# apt update
# apt upgrade
```

When I try to install Steam, `apt` can't install i386 packages:

```
# apt install -f steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Same while trying to install PCSX2

```
# apt install pcsx2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pcsx2:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.8) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5:i386 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

or *wine32*:

```
# apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 4.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to simulate the installation of a package `apt` is complaining about I get the following:

```
apt install -s libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And if I try to install *libgl1:i386* or *libglx-mesa0:i386* I got:

```
apt install libgl1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.1.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
# apt install libglx-mesa0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And then *installing libx11-xcb1:i386*:

```
# apt install libx11-xcb1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1 : Depends: libglx0 (= 1.1.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libx11-xcb1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

```
# apt policy libx11-xcb1{,:i386}
libx11-xcb1:
  Installed: 2:1.6.12-1
  Candidate: 2:1.6.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.6.12-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.6.7-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
libx11-xcb1:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.6.7-1
  Version table:
     2:1.6.7-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 Packages
```

---

Here's the content of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# apt policy libx11-xcb1{,:i386}
libx11-xcb1:
  Installed: 2:1.6.12-1
  Candidate: 2:1.6.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.6.12-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:1.6.7-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
libx11-xcb1:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.6.7-1
  Version table:
     2:1.6.7-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 Packages
```

shows the source of the problem: `apt` is unable to install the same version of the package for `i386` as is already installed for `amd64` (which matches Debian testing, not Debian 10). Multiarch packages have to be kept exactly in sync.

To fix this, you’ll have to either downgrade the affected packages to the Debian 10 versions, or install the `i386` versions from Debian testing (potentially upgrading the `amd64` packages if necessary), or switch wholesale to Debian testing.

Incidentally, this means that your setup isn’t a fresh Debian Buster install.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, installing my window manager from Debian testing sources was my first move after finishing installing the system. How did you know it matches Debian testing?

Comment: `rmadison libx11-xcb1` told me ;-).